# How to pad with zeroes to the string using regexp to get a length of 4 (from the beginning to the point)?

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
x <- c("1. Ure.html", "15. Astra basta.html", "16. Mafa of Part 4.html", "16.1 Veka--Cons.pdf")
```

How do I get vector y using regexp? I need add lead zero to string for length 4 from start to point.

```
y <-c("0001. Ure.html", "0015. Astra basta.html", "0016. Mafa of Part 4.html", "0016.1 Veka--Cons.pdf")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` from `stringr` and pad the additional values with 0

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(x, "\\d+", function(m) str_pad(m, 4, pad = '0'))
#[1] "0001. Ure.html"      "0015. Astra basta.html" 
#    "0016. Mafa of Part 4.html" "0016.1 Veka--Cons.pdf"
```

This can also be achieved with `sprintf`

```
str_replace(x, "\\d+", function(m) sprintf('%04s', m))
```

Answer (score 4):

An option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^\\d+", ~ sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x)), x)
#[1] "0001. Ure.html"            "0015. Astra basta.html"   
#[3] "0016. Mafa of Part 4.html" "0016.1 Veka--Cons.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, find the matches

```
m <- regexpr("^\\d+", x)
```

extract and coerce the matches to the desired format and update the match locations in the original vector

```
regmatches(x, m) <- sprintf("%04s", regmatches(x, m))
```